Azure Cosmos DB API - List (ReadFeed) Documents - (401) Unauthorized - PowerShell
Issue
I am getting 401 Unauthorized response on "List (ReadFeed) Documents" API request to an Azure Cosmos DB Collection.
Note: I don't think its a permission issue or a token/authorization issue as the same (with just a couple of modifications) script works fine when you run it retrieve a specific item (Query Documents operation)
Here is the documentation that tells you how to construct tokens (In C# ) Access Control on Cosmos DB Resources. I don't see where I went wrong.
Script
My script is no different than what you can find online. In fact, that's how I started considering this is a new topic for me.
The script:
Import-Module Az.Accounts -MinimumVersion 3.0.0
Import-Module Az.Resources
Import-Module Az.CosmosDB
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

Function Generate-MasterKeyAuthorizationSignature{

    [CmdletBinding()]

    param (

        [string] $Verb,
        [string] $ResourceLink,
        [string] $ResourceType,
        [string] $Date,
        [string] $MasterKey,
        [String] $KeyType,
        [String] $TokenVersion
    )

    $keyBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($MasterKey)
    $sigCleartext = @($Verb.ToLower() + "`n" + $ResourceType.ToLower() + "`n" + $ResourceLink + "`n" + $Date.ToString().ToLower() + "`n" + "" + "`n")
    $bytesSigClear = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($sigCleartext)
    $hmacsha = new-object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 -ArgumentList (, $keyBytes)
    $hash = $hmacsha.ComputeHash($bytesSigClear) 
    $signature = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($hash)
    $key = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode('type='+$KeyType+'&ver='+$TokenVersion+'&sig=' + $signature)

    return $key
}

#$AccountName = "cosmosAccount"
#$ResourceGroupName = "cosmosRG"
#$databaseId = "cosmosDB"
#$containerId = "cosmosContainer"
$KeyType = "master"
$TokenVersion = "1.0"
$itemResourceType = "docs"
$itemResourceLink = "dbs/"+$databaseId+"/colls/"+$containerId+"/docs"
$verbMethod = "get"
$endpoint = "https://$AccountName.documents.azure.com:443/"
$date = Get-Date
$utcDate = $date.ToUniversalTime()
$xDate = $utcDate.ToString('r', [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
$requestUri = "$endpoint$itemResourceLink"
$MasterKey = $(Get-AzCosmosDBAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $AccountName).PrimaryMasterKey
$authKey = Generate-MasterKeyAuthorizationSignature -Verb $verbMethod -ResourceLink $itemResourceLink -ResourceType $itemResourceType -Date $xDate -MasterKey $MasterKey -KeyType $KeyType -TokenVersion $TokenVersion

$header = @{

        "authorization"         = "$authKey";
        "x-ms-version"          = "2018-12-31";
        "x-ms-date"             = "$xDate";
    }

try {
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $requestUri -Headers $header -Method $verbMethod
    Write-Host "Read item response = "$result
    return "ReadItemSuccess";
}
catch {
    # Dig into the exception to get the Response details.
    # Note that value__ is not a typo.
    Write-Host "StatusCode:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ 
    Write-Host "Exception Message:" $_.Exception.Message
    echo $_.Exception|format-list -force
}

The goal
What I am simply trying to achieve is have a script that returns the total number of items in a given collection. The approach is to use the List Documents (from ChangeFeed) operation which the response will contain the _count property which is what I want to retrieve. Simple to state, apparently not so simple to implement, at least using what I know of PowerShell.

It is calculating the number of containers but not the items in the container. If you want total items in the container, you can use query-based approach to get the total count of items.

I've adjusted the post since your comment so it explains my end goal better.

I wrote the script from scratch following the documentation (original script in the question was copy/paste from some Git repo hoping it will save me time and it came with lack of understanding of fundamentals). Comparing the two scripts, I think the single obviously impactful change is the way the $itemResourceLink (or simply $resourceLink according the documentation) is constructed. In the original script it included "docs" at the end like this: $itemResourceLink = "dbs/"+$databaseId+"/colls/"+$containerId+"/docs"
What I have effectively done, is changed it to $itemResourceLink = "dbs/"+$databaseId+"/colls/"+$containerId" and moved the "docs" part to the $requestUri variable going from this "$endpoint$itemResourceLink" to this "$endpoint$itemResourceLink/docs". So, the "docs" part of the resource link was not being included in the hashed token. I tested this small change on my newly working script both ways. When the "docs" part was included in the $itemResourceLink, I get the unauthorized error. When I moved it as previously described, the script works. I hope this helps.
Here is the full script if needed (not polished by any sense):
Import-Module Az.Accounts -MinimumVersion 3.0.0
Import-Module Az.Resources
Import-Module Az.CosmosDB
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

# Common variables
$resourceGroupName = "myRg"

# Construct endpoint URL for "List (ReadFeed) Documents" operation
$databaseaccount = "myAccount"
$dbid = "myDB"
$collid = "myContainer"
$endpoint = "https://$databaseaccount.documents.azure.com/"

# Construct authorization token (format): type={typeoftoken}&ver={tokenversion}&sig={hashsignature}
$typeoftoken = "master" # master: use master primary key as the base for the hash signature.
$tokenversion = "1.0" # The only current option available.

#$hashsignature:# Denotes the hashed token signature. In other words:
    # We first create a hash using a payload driven by the Cosmos resource itself.
    # Then we sign that hash using the Cosmos account's primary master key.
    # At the recieving endpoint, this information will be unravelled back to plain text and compared to information present in the request and its header to authorize and validate the request.
    # The payload is based on the 4 components using the following format: "{verb}\n{resourceType}\n{resourceLink}\n{date}\n\n"
    # All values are case-sensitive and must be lowercase.
    # The same date will also be used part of the request header x-ms-date

$verb = "get" # Must be lower case.
$resourceType = "docs" # For this request as per "List (ReadFeed) Documents" documentation.
$resourceLink =  "dbs/$dbid/colls/$collid" # For this request: dbs/{databaseId}/colls/{containerId} as per "List (ReadFeed) Documents" documentation.
$xmsdate = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString('R')  # The date of the request per RFC 1123 date format expressed in Coordinated Universal Time
$payload = @($verb.ToString().ToLower()+"`n" `
             +$resourceType.ToString().ToLower()+"`n" `
             +$resourceLink.ToString().ToLower()+"`n" `
             +$xmsdate.ToString().ToLower()+"`n`n")
    
# To compute the signature we use the SHA256 based Hash-based Message Authentication Code (HMAC) function with the CosmosDB Key as the secret.
# Ensure that the master key used in the hashsignature is decoded using MIME RFC2045 as it's Base64 encoded.
# Ensure that the authorization string is Base64 encoded using MIME RFC2045 so it's URL safe in the request header.
$key = $(Get-AzCosmosDBAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $databaseaccount).PrimaryMasterKey
$hmacSha256 = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 # Create an instance of HMACSHA256 (HMAC using SHA256 hashing function)
$hmacSha256.Key = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($key) # Update the instance's key with ours.
$hashPayload = $hmacSha256.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($payload)) # Compute the signature from the payload
$signature = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($hashPayload) # Encode the signature to Base64 to be URL safe.
$authSet = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("type=$typeoftoken&ver=$tokenversion&sig=$signature") # Encode the authorization token as per the documentation specification.

# Request headers construction (only headers required for GET operation)
$Authorization = $authSet # Authorization token

$header = @{
        "Authorization"         = "$Authorization";
        "x-ms-version"          = "2018-12-31";
        "x-ms-date"             = $($xmsdate.ToString().ToLower());
        "x-ms-max-item-count"   = "1000";
    }
$requestURI = "$endpoint$resourceLink/docs"
$contentType= "application/json"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $requestURI -Headers $header -Method $verb -ContentType $contentType -ResponseHeadersVariable responseHeader

